# ~振り切れていれば expression

Tags: grammar

> 最初は確かに国民から歓迎されていたはずである。
> だがマッドハルトはとんでもない男だった。ようするに、どんな方向であっても振り切れていれば民衆はついてこられなくなってしまうのだ。

What does the word 振り切れていれば mean in this sentence? I tried to look up some sentences from Google but I'm still not quite sure.

> どちらかに迷いなく振り切れていれば 今回はこういう方向の映画なんだと理解できるが 今流行の現実的なシリアス風に作り直したという上で
> 完全にリアル無視な 世界有数の諜報機関の極秘情報が ノートパソコンに入っていたり

source: https://cinema.pia.co.jp/imp/153173/902954/

> 犯人の男が出てきたあたりでノンフィクションなのなフィクションなのか曖昧になってきます。 どちらかに振り切れていれば星5でした。。

source: https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/customer-reviews/R20L59ITSKWAT/

From those sentences, I'm assuming it's something like `no matter how you put it...`. Is this interpretation correct and does it apply to the first sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

振り切る can mean [several things](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%8C%AF%E5%88%87%E3%82%8B/#jn-195622), but those uses in the question mean something like *to push to the end, focus exclusively on sth*. Not listed in the definition, but it is close to the definition 4 '十分に振る。振り抜く。'  Rather than a bat, the visual image of 振り切る in the question is [this](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/11017385.html) kind of speed meter where the indicator is above the max possible speed.

Concretely, the uses in the questions mean:

1. Pushing something completely in some direction. Essentially meaning マッドハルト's policy(?) is extremist (in some sense).
2. Focusing on entertainment aspect or on serious aspect (see the preceding paragraph '１５分は大娯楽アクション その後は地味なシリアスドラマ。').
3. Telling the story as fiction or as non-fiction without leaving ambiguities.

Comment: I guess the lexeme that involves the "needle on a meter" sense is "[振り切れる](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8A%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B)" (goo辞書 has no entry for it)  instead of "振り切る", though I suspect a possible admixture of the "十分に振る, 振り抜く" sense in the second and third instances.